# Japanese live action movie about a special group hunting monsters. eg Liquid Monster

Tags: story-identification, movie

A live action movie about an elite MIB-like group that hunted monsters in modern japan (could have been Chinese though). Involved firearms, significant wirework, and stunt driving.

The monsters came in many different kinds of forms - the hero's had categories of monster type, I think the main villain at the end took the form of a jumbo jet to attack the heroes, but the monsters could physically surround a hero's car like a layer of transparent jelly, with cries from the main protagonists of "Liquid Monster!"
(note: I watched an English dub so unclear what these monsters would have been called in the original language or in subtitles)

This is not the same liquid monster from the anime Ultraman.

The movie was dark (in terms of lighting) being almost exclusively set at night. It was not a comedy, but contained numerous wisecracks as action movies so frequently do.

The action was somewhat frenetic - like a Jackie Chan movie- fast paced. The main boss villain flew in jumbo jet-form in a model set - moving very much the same way that Gyaos moved in Gamera Vs Gyaos, up and down a model highway.

I don't remember when it came out, but I saw I think it was from somewhere around 1985.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I stumbled upon my own answer a little while ago - its [*Wicked City*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0105869/?ref_=fn_al_tt_3) from 1992 - the live action movie, not the anime.

> Taki is assigned to go after Daishu, a businessman who is suspected by the police to be selling the drug "happiness", a drug from the Rapter's world that causes people to "evaporate" if they stop taking it. Actually it is another group of Rapters that are selling the happiness. The second group attacks Daishu's group, and eventually Taki, Daishu, and Daishu's daughter join forces to fight the evil Rapters. Lots of psychic powers, shape changing and general weirdness.